# I'm having trouble using the Frobenius Method to solve $x^2 \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}-2x \frac{dy}{dx}+2y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, frobenius-method

I've successfully found the first solution ($y_1=c_1 x^2$) using the Frobenius Method, but when it comes to finding the other solution ($y_2=c_2 x$), I get an recurring relation on the summation that reduces to $[n(n-1)]c_n$. Since in this case we do have an integer $n \geq 1$ that can make the relation zero, we can't just say $c_n=0$. How do I get around this block?

Comment: Fix the typo in the equation.

Comment: Please document at least some of the steps and intermediate results of your power/Laurent/Puiseux series computation. With your coefficient equation you should have gotten a power offset of $k=1$ giving $y=x^1(c_0+c_1x)$ as correct solution.

Comment: This is an Euler equation.  There's a much easier way to solve it than Frobenius.

Answer (score 1):

$$y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^n$$
$$y'=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n nx^{n-1}$$
$$y''=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n n(n-1)x^{n-2}$$
$$x^2y''-2xy'+2y=0=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(n(n-1)-2n+2 \right)c_nx^n$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n-2)(n-1)c_nx^n=0$$
This has to be true any $x$. Thus, for any $n\neq 1$ and $n\neq 2$ this implies $c_n=0$.

For $n=1$ and $n=2$ the terms  $(n-2)(n-1)c_nx^n$ are nul any $x$. So, $c_1$ and $c_2$ can be any constants. The only two remaining terms are :
$$y=c_1x+c_2x^2 \qquad \text{any } c_1 , c_2$$

Comment: How come you did not move the index over one every time you derived? (i.e. $y'=\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n n x^{n-1}$)

Comment: Because there is not $y'$ in the ODE, but $xy'=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n n x^n$. So there is no need to move the index since the power of $x$ is not $n-1$, but is $n$. The same for $x^2y''$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
y=\sum c_nx^{k+n}\implies 
\left\{\begin{aligned}
0&=(n+k)(n+k-1)c_{n}-2(n+k)c_{n}+2c_n\\
&=(n+k-2)(n+k-1)c_{n}
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
The indicial equation for $n=0$ has solutions $k=1$ and $k=2$. The case $k=2$ is contained in the case $k=1$ which then implies $c_n=0$ for $n\ge2$, $c_0,c_1$ are free leading to $y=c_0x^{1+0}+c_1x^{1+1}$.

Comment: What do you mean the case $k=2$ is contained in the case $k=1$?

Comment: In the case $k=2$ you get the coordinate equations $n(n+1)c_n=0$ which implies $c_n=0$ for $n\ge 1$. Thus you get the solution family $y=c_0x^{2+0}$, which is contained in the solution family for $k=1$. This happens always when the difference of the roots of the indicial equation is integer.

Comment: I agree with your indicial equation and for $n=0$, I also got $k=1$ and $k=2$ as solutions. When I plugged in $k=1$ and $k=2$, I got $[n(n+1)]c_n$ and $[n(n-1)]c_n$, respectively. For $k=1$, this is fine, as no integer $n \geq 1$ can make $[n(n+1)]$ zero. For $k=2$, though this reasoning does not hold up. This was my original problem.

Comment: I still do not see your problem. You get 2 free parameters, as expected for an ODE of order 2. No one said that the two solution families have to be disjoint.

Comment: No, of course not. I'm just having trouble understanding how you can relate the two families of solutions to say that the solution family for $k=2$ is contained in the solution family for $k=1$.

Comment: We seem to have switched cases. Under my convention, for $k=1$ I get the equation $n(n-1)c_n=0$ and for $k=2$ the equation $(n+1)nc_n=0$. The last one would also have $c_{-1}$ as free parameter, but there is no such coefficient in the ansatz.

Comment: Sorry about that. Regardless, though, how can you relate the two families to say one is included in the other?